# Android Device not visible in Eclipse under Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I cannot not deal with one problem. I would like to connect my Android device via USB and deploy apps directly on it. Sounds easy, doesn't it? :) I use:

Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse (Android Developer Tools)
Samsung Galaxy Ace (GT 5830)

What I've established after googling is:

My rules file (51-android.rules):

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="689e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Running: adb devices effects in

```
List of devices attached 
S58307e7XXX device
```

But when I enter Project-> RunConfiuration -> Target, I cannot see my device available.

Any tips?

Comment: Did you enable debugging mode?

Comment: As well as enabling debug mode on the device, make sure you've restarted Eclipse since you made the change. I've had random instances where an adb restart resulted in Eclipse not talking to it (on Fedora).

Comment: @meda Yes, I have debug enabled.

Comment: _But when I enter Project-> RunConfiuration -> Target, I cannot see my device available_ --- Do you see your device as disabled?

Comment: @shoerat No - there is nothing apart from Virtual Devices.

Comment: Problem is solved - Real device is not was not visible in Run Configuration -> Target,but when I change Run Configuration to "Always prompt to pick device" my device is available as a one of possible choice.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this thing works for me (I am not sure if your installation has the same problem with permissions):

```
adb kill-server
# or
sudo adb kill-server

sudo adb devices # side effect: start the server as superuser
adb devices # see if the devices are visible now
```

Ideally, you should do the vendor id stuff, the above is a lazy man's workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps:

1) Find usb vendor id of your device you can find in following link:  http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html.

If your device is not listed there then you can get vendor id using "lsusb" command and find your device usb vendor id.

2) Add your device id in 51-android.rules file

3) kill and restart Adb server using follwoing command:

**adb kill-server**  then **adb start-server**